# Opening multiple files stripping the name and save after some calculations

Tags: python, arcgis

I have a folder with some raster files that look like this: us_ppt_1971_2000_01.asc, us_tmax_1971_2000_02.asc, us_tmin_1971_2000_03.asc,...

I want to open these files from an input folder, do some calculations based on each file, and save the results in an output folder.

All the code is running fine and I can even save the results if I create a dictionary with the new names I want for each input file. But I can never know which input file is saved under which name.

So now I want to open each file, do the calculations and then save the new file with a shorter name stripped from the input file name, say "ppt_01", so I can recognize it.

Here is the code that is working but which saves the files randomly, meaning, the ppt is saved as tmax or the tmin is samed as ppt:

```
import ...
workDirectory="I:\\PRISM\\M stuff"
inputDirectory=workDirectory+"\\in"
inputDirectoryPrism=workDirectory+"\\in\\prism"
resultsDirectory=workDirectory+"\\results" 
...
...

maps = ["PP1", "PP2", "PP3", "PP4", "PP5", "PP6", "PP7", "PP8", "PP9",  "PP10", "PP11", "PP12",
        "TMX1", "TMX2", "TMX3", "TMX4", "TMX5", "TMX6", "TMX7", "TMX8", "TMX9",  "TMX10", "TMX11", "TMX12",
        "TMN1", "TMN2", "TMN3", "TMN4", "TMN5", "TMN6", "TMN7", "TMN8", "TMN9",  "TMN10", "TMN11", "TMN12"]

nr=0

for file in glob.glob( os.path.join(inputDirectoryPrism, '*.asc') ):                                                
        ...
        some calculations
        ...
        # Process: Zonal Statistics as Table    
        # THIS IS WHERE I SAVE MY FILE
        arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa(outputDirectory+"\\subcat_diss_shp.shp", "GRIDCODE", outputDirectory+"\\us_ppt_di", resultsDirectory+"\\"+maps[nr]+".dbf", "DATA", "MEAN")   
        nr = nr + 1
```

And here is the code that I am trying but which gives me the error "workspace is invalid output workspace":

```
import ...
workDirectory="I:\\PRISM\\M stuff"
inputDirectory=workDirectory+"\\in"
inputDirectoryPrism=workDirectory+"\\in\\prism"
resultsDirectory=workDirectory+"\\results" 
...
...

nr=0

for file in glob.glob( os.path.join(inputDirectoryPrism, '*.asc') ):                                                
        name1 = file[3:]
        name2= name1[:-16]
        name3= file[17:]
        name4=name3[:-3]
        ...
        some calculations
        ...
        # Process: Zonal Statistics as Table    
        # THIS IS WHERE I SAVE MY FILE          
        arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa(outputDirectory+"\\subcat_diss_shp.shp", "GRIDCODE", outputDirectory+"\\us_ppt_di", resultsDirectory+"\\"+name2+name4[nr]".dbf", "DATA", "MEAN") 
        nr = nr + 1
```

It looks like resultsDirectory+"\"+name2+name4[nr]".dbf" is not a good way to store the files.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please try to condense your code down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I made the code shorter now.

Comment: I have found a solution. The problem was with the directory where I was saving the files. I kept the second code but replaces the last to last line with arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa(outputDirectory+"\\subcat_diss_shp.shp", "GRIDCODE", outputDirectory+"\\us_ppt_di", file+".dbf", "DATA", "MEAN"). Should I delete the post altogether or leave it here? I am not sure if this is useful for other users or not?

Comment: you can always self-answer the question if you feel it would be useful to others. Explain why the code change solved the problem for you.